# regression on dummies vs mean as an estimator

Tags: regression, econometrics, stata, standard-error

If I saturate my regression and run `y` on  dummy variables, is the individual coefficient for each group identical to the mean as an estimator?

While I find this to be true, the standard errors estimated for each coefficient for the regression are not equal to the standard error of the mean in my statistical software (Stata).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard errors are different because with regression you assume there is one residual standard error, while if you compute the means and  standard deviations separately for each group the standard deviations that go into the computation of the standard errors can obviously differ. If your data are homoscedastic, then the two ways of estimating will match pretty closely, but if they are  heteroscedastic then you will see differences. Here I use Stata too, but the calculations are standard:

```
. clear all

. 
. // homoscedasticity
. set obs 4000
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 4,000

. gen x = ceil(_n/1000)

. gen y = rnormal(x,4.5)

. reg y ibn.x, hascons

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     4,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 3996)      =     78.89
       Model |  4950.21678         3  1650.07226   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  83580.8069     3,996  20.9161178   R-squared       =    0.0559
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0552
       Total |  88531.0237     3,999  22.1382905   Root MSE        =    4.5734

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |
          1  |   1.103654   .1446241     7.63   0.000     .8201097    1.387197
          2  |   2.095734   .1446241    14.49   0.000      1.81219    2.379278
          3  |   3.038795   .1446241    21.01   0.000     2.755251    3.322339
          4  |    4.10504   .1446241    28.38   0.000     3.821496    4.388584
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. table x, c(mean y semean y)

----------------------------------
        x |    mean(y)      sem(y)
----------+-----------------------
        1 |   1.103654    .1485253
        2 |   2.095734    .1463067
        3 |   3.038795     .142503
        4 |    4.10504    .1410388
----------------------------------

. 
. // heteroscedasticity
. gen y2 = rnormal(x, 2+x )

. reg y2 ibn.x, hascons

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     4,000
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 3996)      =     82.27
       Model |  5568.19285         3  1856.06428   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   90149.325     3,996  22.5598911   R-squared       =    0.0582
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0575
       Total |  95717.5179     3,999  23.9353633   Root MSE        =    4.7497

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          y2 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |
          1  |   .8249027   .1501995     5.49   0.000     .5304279    1.119378
          2  |   1.996436   .1501995    13.29   0.000     1.701962    2.290911
          3  |   3.191657   .1501995    21.25   0.000     2.897182    3.486132
          4  |   3.925213   .1501995    26.13   0.000     3.630738    4.219687
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. table x, c(mean y2 semean y2)

----------------------------------
        x |   mean(y2)     sem(y2)
----------+-----------------------
        1 |   .8249027    .0946577
        2 |   1.996436    .1287183
        3 |   3.191657    .1651861
        4 |   3.925213    .1934544
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

So when I perform this in R, I get pretty agreeable results between taking means/standard errors between groups and a linear model.  My standard errors are off by a small margin, most likely because I am incorrectly accounting for degrees of freedom.

Here is some code I'm using:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

group<-sample(c('a','b','c'), size = 300, replace = T)
X = model.matrix(~group-1)
b = c(1,2,3)
y = X %*% b + rnorm(length(group), 0, 10)

#model summary

model = lm(y~group-1)
summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ group - 1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-29.0956  -6.9058   0.4483   6.7912  22.4393 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
groupa   0.1621     0.9432   0.172 0.863683    
groupb   2.8421     1.0744   2.645 0.008599 ** 
groupc   3.3110     0.9520   3.478 0.000581 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.847 on 297 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06049,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.051 
F-statistic: 6.374 on 3 and 297 DF,  p-value: 0.0003365



tibble(group, y) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(mn = mean(y),
            se = sd(y)/sqrt(n()-1))

`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group    mn    se
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     0.162 0.963
2 b     2.84  1.10 
3 c     3.31  0.927
```

Is this the sort of discrepency you're observing, or is it larger?

@Dimitry you can perhaps use these codes ...

```
# code for lm std
res <- model$res
s <- sum(res^2/297)
V <- solve(t(X)%*%X) * s
sd <- sqrt(diag(V))
sd

# Heteroscedasticity robust covariance matrix ()
bread <- solve(t(X)%*%X) # diag group counts inverted
butter <- t(X)%*%diag(res^2)%*% X # sum of within group squared residual
VV <- bread %*% butter %*% bread  
sqrt(diag(VV))

# Same as sqrt(diag(VV)) but with corresponding df
tibble(group, y) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(mn = sum((y-mean(y))^2),
            se = sqrt(mean((y-mean(y))^2))/sqrt(n()))
```

Comment: At first I thought mine was larger, but I can see that in proportional terms they are similar to yours (i.e. for me the standard error of the mean is 429.49 and from the regression it is 411.363). So is my understanding then that it is something to do with the dof adjustment in the regression?

Comment: I think the main reason for the deviance in @Demetris example is that lm() assumes homoscedasticity and therefore use all residuals to estimate varience of error term. In the second calculation example however only the within group variation is used. Then there is some degrees of fredom where $sd(y)^2 \not= sum((y-mean(y))^2)$.